# How does a Load generator produce the load in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

- I Need to know how the load generator generate the load.
- When we mentioned 100 `Vusers` in `controller` for a generator ?

  1. whether it generate 100 threads and send parallel ?
  2. is it creating separate connection to send 100 threads or only one ?

Comment: Question is too broad. Can you elaboate more?

Answer (score 1):

The connections are separate for each vuser. Whether each vuser runs in a separate thread or a separate process is configurable. If you select the "per thread" mode, there'll be a separate process for each 50 vusers.